# Callback response from API not getting updated

Tags: php

I have the following response in json format received in a API callback url at my server.

```
{
    "sessionId": "2_MX4xMzExMjU3MX5-MTQ3MDI1NzY3OTkxOH45QXRr",
    "projectId": "123456",
    "event": "connectionCreated",
    "timestamp": 1470257688309,
    "connection": {
        "id": "c053fcc8-c681-41d5-8ec2-7a9e1434a21e",
        "createdAt": 1470257688143,
        "data": "TOKENDATA"
    }
}
```

I tried the following code to access it and save it in DB:

```
<?php
$str = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
if ($str) {    
// decode JSON
$json = json_decode($str, true);
// get the data
$Session_ID = $json['sessionId'];
$start_time = $json['connection']['createdAt'];

include_once('inc/connection.inc.php'); 
$sql = "INSERT INTO sessmonitor() 
        VALUES (:sessid,:time)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':sessid'=> $Session_ID,
':time'=> $start_time
)
); 
$conn = null;
}
?>
```

I am not receiving any update and receive error:
**Undefined index: connection**

Please what am i doing wrong ??

Comment: Did you include your database connection file/function /class containing the variable `$conn` on that php where you run the query to save the value

Comment: Can you add `var_dump($str)` so you can verify what you are getting from the API callback?

Comment: `$str` is probably not what you are expecting. Testing with a string does not produce the error: https://ideone.com/vOkfOu

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Yes, seems like I am not getting any response from the API. The format is specified in the documentation and correct.